# C++ initializing pointer crashes application randomly?

Tags: c++, pointers, crash

I have following code:

```
class RawModel{
    public:
        RawModel(GLuint id, GLuint count);
        GLuint* getID(void);
        GLuint* getVertexCount(void);
    private:
        GLuint *vaoID;
        GLuint *verts;
};

RawModel::RawModel(GLuint id, GLuint count){
    *vaoID = id;
    *verts = count;
}

GLuint* RawModel::getID(void){
    return vaoID;
}

GLuint* RawModel::getVertexCount(void){
    return verts;
}
```

But upon running, it crashes.
If I don't create an instance of this class, my Application runs fine, but the Constructor seems to be crashing, and I don't know why. (I'm fairly new to C++).

I need to use pointers, because of the function `glDeleteVertexArrays()` calling for a Pointer as a 2nd parameter.

Comment: Use `nullptr` instead of 0 and compiler will tell you what is wrong

Comment: Explain this to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): `*vaoID = 0;`.

Comment: ...and initialize members in the ctor initializer list not the body of the constructor.

Comment: @Slava the compiler gives me a TypeCastException, but since I was actually using the Parameters to initialize, and that didn't work either, it cant be that.

Comment: Then show actual code, not your interpretation. Why do you have pointers and why do you return pointers instead of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
*vaoID = 0;
```

is not initializing a pointer. Instead it is dereferencing a pointer and trying to assing a zero to the pointee. However, there is no pointee. Dereferencing a pointer that does not point to something is undefined behaviour.

Initializing the pointer would be

```
vaoID = nullptr;
```

But note that after this the pointer still points to nothing. You will have to create an object to make the pointer point to it.

Btw it is not clear why you use pointers in the first place. I dont know that lib, but most likely you can simply have instances as members:

```
class RawModel{
 //...
private:
    GLuint vaoID;
    GLuint verts;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to initialize pointers, initialize them, not data they point to:

```
RawModel::RawModel(GLuint id, GLuint count){
    vaoID = nullptr;
    verts = nullptr;
}
```

but even better use member initialization:

```
RawModel::RawModel(GLuint id, GLuint count) :
    vaoID( nullptr ),
    verts( nullptr )
{
}
```

but it is not clear why you have pointers in class and return pointers in methods, instead of storing and returning them by value.

Comment: I need to return pointers because the function `glDeleteVertexArrays` calls for a pointer as a 2nd parameter.

Comment: And you want to pass one element array to that function? And why count is a pointer?

Comment: You whole code is a mess, you suppose to pass pointer to array, and array needs to be created by `glGenVertexArrays` and memory allocated. You better use `std::vector<GLuint>` for it. And it is not clear why you pass one `id` to it and count.